# How to detect a stopword in a given string and convert only that stopword from sentence case or uppercase to lower case

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, nlp, stop-words

I have the following code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
import re
text='Director Of IT'
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english'))+ r')\b\s*') #remove stop words
textmod5 = pattern.sub('', text)
print(textmod5)
```

I would like to make only the stop word 'Of' into lower case 'of'. How to achieve that using the same above expression.

I have tried the following but with no avail

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english'))+ r')\b\s*'.lower)
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words.lower(('english')))+ r')\b\s*')
```

What would be the correct pattern to achieve my objective

Current output : Director Of IT

Required Output : Director of IT

Comment: So, try replacing `stopwords.words('english')` with `[x.lower() if x == 'Of' else x for x in  stopwords.words('english')]`

Comment: Or do you mean that you want the output to contain a lowercase `of`? Then instead of `textmod5 = pattern.sub('', text)` use `textmod5 = pattern.sub(lambda x: 'of' if x.group()=='Of' else x.group(), text)`

Comment: Please clarify what exactly works for you (if either)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your answer. What i was specifically asking was, what i have to do in the below line of code itself to make the stop word 'Of' to 'of'. I understand that it would make all the stopwords into lowercase and I am ok with that. `pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english'))+ r')\b\s*')`

Comment: So, `pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join([x.lower() if x == 'Of' else x for x in stopwords.words('english')])+ r')\b\s*')`, right? Just as I explained in my top comment.

Comment: No the below solution from you is unfortunately not working for me . I still get 'Director Of IT' instead of 'Director of IT'   `pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join([x.lower() if x == 'Of' else x for x in stopwords.words('english')])+ r')\b\s*')`

Comment: Also rather than for specific case like 'Of' I would like to make all the stop words lowercase through this line of code itself. `pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english'))+ r')\b\s*')`

Comment: It is impossible, you can only define *what you match*  with a pattern, but not *what you get in the output*. `re.sub` removes the matches. If your pattern does not match `Of` it will be kept in the original string. If you make your pattern match `Of`, it will get removed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok I understand. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see another problem here: how do you distinguish between `IT`, which should not be touched, and `it` which is in your list of stopwords when you're converting to lower case or using an ignore case flag?

You could use a replace function paired with a list of words that should be put to lower case and another list of words that should be ignored. That would also necessitate adding the ignore case flag to your expression and tweak the spacing a little. For example:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
import re

def remove_or_lower(m):
    exceptions = ['of'] # put these in lower case
    ignored = ['IT'] # don't touch these
    cap = m.group(1) # captured
    cap_str = cap.strip()
    low = cap.lower() # lowered
    low_str = low.strip()
    return low if low_str in exceptions else cap if cap_str in ignored else ''

text = 'Director Of IT'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\b(?:' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b\s*)', flags=re.IGNORECASE) #remove stop words
textmod5 = pattern.sub(remove_or_lower, text)

print(textmod5)
```

Output:

```
Director of IT
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have issue with IT as such because I am taking care of it via a dictionary set up like below. `dct = {''It': 'IT','it': 'IT','it':'IT','IT':'IT}`                     `textmod4 = re.sub(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(dct)), lambda m: dct[m.group(0)], text)`.       
 What I am looking for is 1) check if a word in a given string is stop word or not (for e.g 'Director Of IT'), 2) if a stop word is present in the string for e.g 'Of' , convert only that stopword into lowercase that is into 'of' from "Of' or 'OF'. Final output should be 'Director of IT'

Comment: Ok, it confused me that in your example you actually removed stop words. But you still have the problem that `it` etc. are in your list of words. As long as you don't exclude them somehow, any action done to any other stop word will be done to them, e.g. you'll get `Director of it`.